# ThreeJS ShaderMaterial Texture Issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

Using three.js r71. I can't figure out why my texture is not being read by the `ShaderMaterial`. The plane is just black. I need a pair of fresh eyes to help me pinpoint what is wrong.

Thanks a lot !

Here's the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="testshdr.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
   
    <!-- Shaders -->
    <script id="vertexShader" 
            type="x-shader/x-vertex" >

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main(){
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * 
                    modelViewMatrix * 
                    vec4(position, 1.0);

    }

    </script>

    <script name="no_effect"
            id="fragmentShader_0"
            type="x-shader/x-fragment" >

    varying vec2 vUv;

    uniform sampler2D editImg;

    void main(){
      vec4 myTexture = texture2D(editImg, vUv);
      gl_FragColor = vec4 (myTexture.r, 
                           myTexture.g, 
                           myTexture.b, 
                           1.0);

    }

    </script>
   
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var tst = new TestShdr();
    </script>

  </body>
  
</html>
```

And here's the JS:

```js
var TestShdr = function () {
  'use strict';
  
  var
    SCENE,
    RENDERER,
    CAMERA,
    GEO,
    MAT,
    OBJ,
    TEX,
    UNIFS,
    VS,
    FS;
  
  SCENE = new THREE.Scene();
  RENDERER = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  RENDERER.setSize(256, 256);
  
  CAMERA = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(56, 1, 0.1, 1000);
  
  SCENE.add(CAMERA);
  CAMERA.position.z = 5;
  
  TEX = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('1107.jpg');
  
  UNIFS = {
    editImg: { type: 't', value: TEX}
  };
  VS = $('#vertexShader').html();
  FS = $('#fragmentShader_0').html();
  
  GEO = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1);
  MAT = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({uniforms: UNIFS,
                                  vertexShader: VS,
                                  fragmentShader: FS
                                 });
  OBJ = new THREE.Mesh(GEO, MAT);
  SCENE.add(OBJ);
  
  document.body.appendChild(RENDERER.domElement);
  
  RENDERER.render(SCENE, CAMERA);
  
};
```

Comment: Well for one you aren't waiting for the texture to load. textures load asynchronously. It won't be available at the time you render given your code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
TEX = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('1107.jpg', {}, function() {
    RENDERER.render(SCENE, CAMERA);
});
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks guys :)

Comment: And that's why it didn't work in the first place... I simply forgot to call the onload as an anonymous function **facepalm**